# Rails Images issue

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have something like this in my rails app:

```
 <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="gal5.jpg" title="something">
    <img hspace="12" src="images/gal5thumb.jpg" alt="Something" />
 </a>
```

I have my images saved in /assets/images. For some reason this doesn't work but when I save the images on some website like cloudinary and then use the url everything works perfectly. Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong?

I am using rails 5 on Ubuntu.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

=> If you place images in your app/assets/images directory, then you should be able to call the image directly with no prefix in the path. ie. `image_url('logo.png')` or `asset_url('gal5thumb.jpg')`

```
 <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="gal5.jpg" title="something">    
  <img hspace="12" src="/assets/gal5thumb.jpg" alt="Something" />
 </a>
```

Or

```
 <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="gal5.jpg" title="something">    
  <img hspace="12" src="<%=asset_path('gal5thumb.jpg')%>" alt="Something" />
 </a>
```

Or

=>  If you are using it inline in the view, then you will need to use the built in image_tag helper in rails to output your image. without prefixing

```
<%= image_tag "gal5thumb.jpg", alt: "something", hspace: "12" %>
```